# I want to map login page after executing application and when i logout it

Tags: javascript, java, maven-3

I have implemented application in mvc .When i run that application it goes on login page but i want that same page when i logout the session.
Is it possible to map same page two times in controller.

Comment: You have a route that goes in the logout controller, here you can redirect your user to  login.html or whatever is called your login page

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It should be just the matter of routing the application to the logout controller. The code would look something similar to that of the below code.

```
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {            
        //log out the user
        return RedirectToAction("Login");
    }
```